# MySQL copy distinct values from table to. table

Tags: mysql

One of my table contains data(numbers) that i would like to copy to other table, but problem is that data is not unique there can be 2 or more rows with same data i would like to copy (i need to copy each number only once). Table is around 3 milion records. Is any effcient way to do this?

Comment: Does the second table (into which you are copying) already contains some data ? and you want to ignore those numbers also (from first table), which already exist in the second table ?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? 
`INSERT INTO destination_table ('the_value_field') SELECT DISTINCT('the_value_field') FROM origin_table`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are two columns a, b in your table

```
INSERT INTO new_table (a, b) SELECT 
a, b FROM old_table GROUP BY
a, b HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

you can extend this with more columns.
this will be a slow process and may never complete with huge data.

So, instead copy all values into new_table using

```
 Insert into new_table select * from old_table;
```

and then delete duplicate records from new table . This can be relatively faster and is with an assured completion.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to select only the unique values.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

```
SELECT DISTINCT `val` FROM `table_name`
```

Comment: I cant select whole 3m records at once and when i do it with limits like every 100 000 there is high chance i will catch duplicate on for exanple 1st and 4th select